# Pre Trained Models in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am making a R Shiny app and wanted to know if it was possible to pre train models then input the models as a variable in server.R so that I can just render the result of predict(selected_model, input$data)?

It is not feasible for me to train the models live as they would take too long to train.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: You could save the trained models in a `.RData` file then `load` them at the start of the Shiny app- is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save R object with `save` function

```
save("myobject" file = "myobject.RData")
```

Then load later with

```
load("myobject.RData")
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use `readRDS` and `saveRDS` function rather than save and load